# Service being created twice after destroy

Tags: android, service, background-process

I have a service that send gps updates every 15 mins. The problem is once I destroy my service and start it again, the service running now is 2, when I'm expecting only 1. The previous service is being executed again when I already stopped it and started a new one. For further reference, Here's how I create my service.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, BGService.class);
```

I start the service on a method at a button click:

```
startService(i);
```

Here's my service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
            "MyWakeLock");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendWakeLock);
    handler.postDelayed(sendWakeLock, 1000); // 1 second   
    Log.i("onStart", "onStart");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("onDestroy", "onDestroy");
}

private Runnable sendWakeLock = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {     
        try
        {
            if(!stopSend)
            {
                sendGPSUpdate();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if(wakeLock != null) {
                if(wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    wakeLock.release();
                }
                wakeLock = null;
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 900000);
    }
};

 private void sendGPSUpdate()
 {
     sendBroadcast(intent);
 }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Then back on my activity, I click another button that closes the application, I do this:

```
stopService(i);
finish();
```

Just to add, I have a broad cast reciever:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("Broadcast", "Recieved!");
            UpdateCurrentLocati on();
            if(BGService.wakeLock == null) {
                PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                BGService.wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
                        PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 
                        "Tag");
            }
            if(! BGService.wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                BGService.wakeLock.acquire();
            }
        }
 };
```

Once again, when I launch the application and start the service again, as I said, I'm having two running services that is sending gps updates. This is background process by the way. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you have to use this Service only as long as the Activity lasts, then why not use a 'Bound Service' ?
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: This is the first option that I used since I believed that stopService will suffice.

Comment: how you solve this problem. i am also stuck on it

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see an implementation of onStartCommand in your code, I used it in a following manner:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
 startRecording();// start audio capture in the background
 return  Service.START_STICKY;// maybe you should use START_NOT_STICKY or IntentService
}
```

I have stopped and started this service several time without doubling or any other problem.
There are other options, for example your service will be automatically restarted by Android OS if it stops, you may see the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Edit: When we call startService, a call to onStartCommand is made. If you're calling startService multiple times maybe more than one threads based on you method sendWakeLock are being spawned.

Comment: onStart was deprecated in API level 5, i.e. Android 2.0. Official document says you should use onStartCommand instead. See link below :) 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)

Comment: Changed it to onStartCommand. Still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: So how should I stop the previous thread from running so that I can execute a new one?

Comment: I have this code to remove callbacks handler.removeCallbacks(sendWakeLock);

Comment: you could introduce a boolean flag, although I can see !stopSend. for example a service level member variable boolean isWorking. Set it to true on start of your method and false on the end. Next, check if it's true in the onStartCommand and don't call handler.postDelayed in first place.

Comment: I also tried that. But putting a flag on it doesn't really solve the problem of the two services being executed.

Answer (score 0):

just do **service.stop**.....  before **service.start**.....